# How to pronounce "$\;\setminus\;$" (the symbol for set difference)

Tags: soft-question, notation

A question for English speakers. When using (or reading) the symbol $\setminus$ to denote set difference —

$$A\setminus B=\{x\in A|x\notin B\}$$

— how do you pronounce it?

If you please, indicate in a comment on your answer what region you're from (what dialect you have).

---

This is a poll question. *Please do not repeat answers! Rather, **upvote** an answer if you pronounce the symbol the same way the answerer does, and **downvote** it not at all.* Please don't upvote answers for other reasons. Thanks!

Comment: How do *you* pronounce it?

Comment: @lhf, I upvoted [the relevant answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/114491). `:-)`

Comment: I pronounce it "$\setminus$" of course. How else would I pronounce it?

Comment: I tend to pronounce it "$A$ delete $B$."

Answer (score 26):

$A$ *minus* $B$ seems to be the natural way.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: This is how I say it, and I am a native speaker. This is also why the symbol is named "setminus".

Comment: As an English speaking programmer (not mathematician) that's how I'd say this

Answer (score 16):

I usually say "A without B," but it depends on my mood that day

Comment: If someone said this out loud, without a visual cue, I would have no idea what it means.

Comment: @Carl even within the context of (mathematical) sets? Spoken language is *always* context sensitive and once you have the context I find this entirely understandable and natural.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: yes, even in the context of mathematics I would not recognize "without" to refer to a relative complement unless someone explicitly told me that it did.

Comment: This is the one I use. (US Midwest)

Answer (score 8):

No one's mentioned "$A$ take away $B$" yet.

Comment: But is that the way you in practice pronounce it?

Comment: @Mitch Usually, yes. Especially   when the sets in question are collections of generic objects, such as people, chairs, etc...

Comment: That doesn't sound very mathematical. +1

Answer (score 7):

I pronounce $A \setminus B$ just as the latex code: $A$ *setminus* $B$.

Comment: Reading letters with their latex command names usually puts me off... To hear someone seriously saying *varepsilon* makes me distrust him!

Comment: I should perhaps stop writing this as "A \backslash B"...

Answer (score 2):

In situations such as the theory of automorphic forms/functions, the expression $A\backslash B$ means "$B$ left mod $A$", not set-complement. It is pronounced that way: "B left-mod A".

This is necessary because there are quotients on the right also, which interact with these. It amazes me how much trouble it is to get students to "recover from" thinking that "backslash" could only mean "set complement". I say to them "why not just write '-' for set complement?".

The literature on automorphic what's-its is full of left quotients, notated $A\backslash B$.

Answer (score 1):

Complement of B in A  for A-B  or sometime A difference B

This is more self explaining way to say.. I feel!

Comment: This is what seems to me the right way!

Answer (score 1):

A less B.............................

Comment: This is what I was taught (in Ireland).

Answer (score 1):

I say any of the following (it varies):

"A not B"

"A slash B"

and when I am trying to be clear

"The complement of B in A"

Answer (score 1):

*Prologue*: I usually try NOT to pronounce math symbols or expressions or say it loud in mind as (claimed in folklore) that internal reading seems to hinder 'speed reading' or comprehension. (Note: I am hugely influenced by Eastern arts so may be there is some truth to that. (Meta-note: Feel free to comment on it if you disagree))

*Vote status*: Upvoted for making me look up some links.

*Answer*:

- [Pronunciation guide for mathematical notation](http://www.math.helsinki.fi/engl.pdf)
- Blog on ["Pronunciation Guides for Mathematical Notation, Expressions, and Greek Letters"](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/05/pronunciation-guides-for-mathematical.html)

Answer (score 0):

I say "A slash B".${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I guess there's not too much confusion between this and $A/B$, A modulo B :P