# What does $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$ mean?

Tags: notation

What does $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ mean? I am not getting it what it actually means. I have found it manywhere in real-analysis like in the definition of boundary points of a set. Can anyone tell me what it means really?

Comment: Note also that it is often denoted $\mathbb{R}-S$. But $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ is prefered in classical analysis since it is not really a "subtraction" in the sense of adding and subtracting real numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $S$ is a set and $\Bbb R$ is the set of all real numbers then $$\Bbb R \setminus S = \{x \mid x\in \Bbb R \wedge x \not\in S\}$$ meaning it's the set of all elements $x$ such that $x$ is a real number and $x$ is not an element of the set $S$.

For instance $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ is the set of all real numbers **except** $0$.

This operation is called [relative complement or set difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement).

Comment: I know the difference between sets but didn't know about this notation. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: @user36790 Also, $\mathbb{R}\setminus S=\mathbb{R}\cap S^C$, etc. If you knew to typeset $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ using `\setminus` ... I'm somewhat surprised. Well, now you have several ways of looking at the notation.

Comment: @MagicMan: It was bothering when I was not getting the required result. However, I fixed it myself!

Answer (score 4):

That symbols means *set difference*. It is called `\setminus` in $\TeX.$

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A \setminus B$ is the set of elements in $A$ but not in $B$.

Comment: I've also heard it as "A remove B."

Comment: @Bob1123, see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114488/how-to-pronounce-setminus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , sir. I was at a dilemma which ans to accept. But, since you have got already 4+ , I better deemed it apt enough to pick the later. Nevertheless, thanks for helping me, sir.

Comment: @user36790, no problem.